# Testing Kit to Transit Heathrow to Belfast?

Tags: uk, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, covid-19

Northern Ireland is the only part of the UK that does not require the day 2 & 8 Covid test kit for international arrivals.

I'm trying to anticipate whether, when connecting in Heathrow, I will be asked for proof of purchase of this test kit.

Heathrow website states:
"If you have a boarding pass issued for your onward journey, you will be able to stay airside during your connection. This means that when you arrive into Heathrow, you will not need to pass through immigration or customs and can follow the purple signs for connections and make your way to the departing gate once it opens."

I have read in pre-Covid forum posts that there is at least some form of passport control when transferring from international to UK domestic flight.

Do you think the UK will demand the proof of testing kit? Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.